# Retrieve files after xampp uninstalled

Tags: xampp

I have uninstalled Xampp in my system. I have taken a backup of databases, but I missed to take folders inside htdocs. Is there any way to retrieve my folders.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not; if the folders are gone then I would say your only hope is restoring from backup or an undelete utility.

Sorry for the bad news.

Answer (score 1):

download shadowexplorer. Its is a system restore software that will find shadow copies on the system or specified folder through selected restore date. It is really easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows File Recovery** CLI undelete utility. Currently available for Windows 10 2004 and above.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/p/windows-file-recovery/9n26s50ln705

Answer (score -1):

I once accidently deleted my htdocs folder along with xampp, i immediately downloaded shadowexplorer and ran it, found all my files.

Comment: This is not an answer! This is a comment. Please, post it in the comment area.

Comment: It's not an answer. It's a comment! Should be in the comment area.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it by using shadowexplorer software.